# Perform Calculation on One DataFrame Based on the Common Columns of a Second DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume the two `DataFrames` have equal columns but different rows even though the examples are equal in length.  I was able to find the commonalities of the two DataFrames.  I want to use that similarity to perform calculations on one of the DataFrames and put the result in another DataFrames.  In summary, I want to update the selling price of the Nike products to be 10% higher than Adidas products with the constraint that they're both in the same category and size.

```py
percent = 1.10

data1 = {
    'item_id': [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004],
    'brand': ['Adidas', 'Adidas', 'Adidas', 'Adidas'],
    'category_id': [241, 241, 238, 717],
    'size': [8, 7.5, 9, 10],
    'cost_price': [8.02, 4.94, 1.49, 18.44],
    'unit_price': [12.89, 7.98, 2.44, 29.53]
}

data2 = {
    'item_id': [1005, 1006, 1007, 1008],
    'brand': ['Nike', 'Nike', 'Nike', 'Nike'],
    'category_id': [512, 241, 604, 717],
    'size': [7.5, 8, 9, 10],
    'cost_price': [35.90, 11.62, 15.03, 20.53],
    'unit_price': [48.14, 16.29, 21.09, 28.20]
}

adidas = pd.DataFrame(data1)
nike = pd.DataFrame(data2)

columns = ['category_id', 'size']
common = adidas [columns].merge(nike[columns])
common
   category_id  size
0          241   8.0
1          717  10.0

df = pd.concat([adidas, nike]).merge(common)
df
   item_id   brand  category_id  size  cost_price  unit_price
0     1001  Adidas          241   8.0        8.02       12.89
1     1006    Nike          241   8.0       11.62       16.29
2     1004  Adidas          717  10.0       18.44       29.53
3     1008    Nike          717  10.0       20.53       28.20
```

If they were a dictionary, I would do:

```py
cat_match = []
for catid in data2['category_id']:
    try:
        index = data1['category_id'].index(catid)
        cat_match.append(index)
    except ValueError:
        pass

size_match = []
for size in data2['size']:
    try:
        index = data1['size'].index(size)
        size_match(index)
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(cat_match)
[0, 3]
print(size_match)
[1, 0, 2, 3]
```

I would then calculate the "unit_cost" (aka selling price) of `data1` by making the markup = unit_cost * percent at index 0 and 3.  Next, I would search for the same index in `data2` and create a new row called "new_sell" with the markup calculated which will be added to data2 dictionary.

I also tried the below code from another SO answer but I received an error.

```py
df2['new_sell'] = df2.apply(lambda row: row['unit_price'] * 1.10 if row['category_id'] == df1['category_id'] and row['size'] == df1['size'] else None, axis=1)
...
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Both attempts are quite messy and convoluted.  Is there an easier way to achieve the following using pandas?

```py
df2
   item_id   brand  category_id  size  cost_price  unit_price  sell_price
0     1006    Nike          241   8.0       11.62       16.29       14.18 # (12.89*1.1)
1     1008    Nike          717  10.0       20.53       28.20       32.48 # (29.53*1.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a left-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and multiple by 1.1 (for example with [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html)):

```
cols = ['category_id', 'size']
nike['sell_price'] = (nike[cols]
                      .merge(adidas[cols+ ['unit_price']],
                             on=cols, how='left')
                      .eval('unit_price*1.1') # or ['unit_price'].mul(1.1)
                     )
```

If you don't want to modify `nike` and rather want a new DataFrame:

```
cols = ['category_id', 'size']
out = (nike
       .merge(adidas[cols+ ['unit_price']]
              .rename(columns={'unit_price': 'sell_price'}),
              on=cols, how='left')
       .eval('sell_price=sell_price*1.1')
      )
```

Output:

```
   item_id brand  category_id  size  cost_price  unit_price  sell_price
0     1005  Nike          512   7.5       35.90       48.14         NaN
1     1006  Nike          241   8.0       11.62       16.29      14.179
2     1007  Nike          604   9.0       15.03       21.09         NaN
3     1008  Nike          717  10.0       20.53       28.20      32.483
```

Comment: Eval method doesn't allow for passing in variable due to security concern.  I had to modify your answer a bit to get the results that I wanted by removing the eval and substitute it with out = out [~df ['new_sell'].isnull ()]  and  out ['new_sell'] = out ['new_sell'].mul (percent).

Comment: @dreamzboy `eval('unit_price * @variable')` or `['unit_price'].mul(variable)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use multi-indexing in this case, so you can loop over the category/size combinations. This is my solution:

```
shoes_df = pd.concat([adidas, nike])

shoes_df = shoes_df.set_index(["category_id", "size", "brand"])
shoes_df["new_sell"] = None

all_df = list()
all_brands = shoes_df.index.get_level_values("brand").unique()

for brand_index, brand_df in shoes_df.groupby(["category_id", "size"]):
    available_brands_in_group = brand_df.index.get_level_values("brand")
    missing_brands = all_brands.difference(available_brands_in_group)

    if not missing_brands.any():
        # both nike and adidas are available
        adidas_price = brand_df.loc[(slice(None), slice(None), "Adidas"), "unit_price"]
        nike_price_value = percent * adidas_price.values[0]
        brand_df.loc[(slice(None), slice(None), "Nike"), "new_sell"] = nike_price_value

    # collect all new brand_df with updated prices
    all_df.append(brand_df)

new_shoes_df = pd.concat(all_df)
print(new_shoes_df)
```

The output looks like :

```
                         item_id  cost_price  unit_price new_sell
category_id size brand                                           
238         9.0  Adidas     1003        1.49        2.44     None
241         7.5  Adidas     1002        4.94        7.98     None
            8.0  Adidas     1001        8.02       12.89     None
                 Nike       1006       11.62       16.29   14.179
512         7.5  Nike       1005       35.90       48.14     None
604         9.0  Nike       1007       15.03       21.09     None
717         10.0 Adidas     1004       18.44       29.53     None
                 Nike       1008       20.53       28.20   32.483
```

If you only want the nike dataframe in the same way as you started you can do:

```
nike_df = new_shoes_df.reset_index()
nike_df = nike_df[nike_df["brand"] == "Nike"]
nike_df = nike_df[adidas.columns.to_list() + ["new_sell"]].sort_values("item_id")
```

which yields:

```
    item_id brand  category_id  size  cost_price  unit_price new_sell
4     1005  Nike          512   7.5       35.90       48.14     None
3     1006  Nike          241   8.0       11.62       16.29   14.179
5     1007  Nike          604   9.0       15.03       21.09     None
7     1008  Nike          717  10.0       20.53       28.20   32.483
```